# React Redux Toolkit: No reducer provided for key "myReducer" when importing store to separate files

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to dispatch a redux action on some event outside react component. But when I do `import store from '../../app/store'` in my separate js file containing this event handler, I'm getting the following error inside a component:

`No reducer provided for key "myReducer"`

my files:

store.js:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
// ...
import rootReducer from './rootReducer'

const middleware = //...

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware
});

export default store;
```

rootReducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

// reducers created with createSlice and exported like this: export default SomeFeatureSlice.reducer;
import myReducer from '../features/my/mySlice' 
import SomeFeatureReducer from '../features/some_feature/SomeFeatureSlice'


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    //...
    myReducer,
    SomeFeatureReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

component:

```
// ...
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    some_prop: state.myReducer.some_prop
})
// ...
```

handler:

```
// ...
import store from '../../app/store'
// an action exported this way: export const { myAction } = SomeFeatureSlice.actions;
import { myAction } from '../../features/some_feature/SomeFeatureSlice'
//...
store.dispatch(myAction());
//...
```

index.js:

```
import store from './app/store';
// ...

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.Fragment> 
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.Fragment>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

When I remove `import store` statement from handler everything works fine. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where the "handler.js" file fits into your app.

However:

- It's possible that you've created [a circular import dependency issue](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#exporting-and-using-slices), which will break things because one of the files won't be initialized by the time the store is set up.
- [You shouldn't be importing the store into other files anyway](https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#can-or-should-i-create-multiple-stores-can-i-import-my-store-directly-and-use-it-in-components-myself)

Comment: my handler basically catches an error if such occurred on a remote API call and is intended to update a flag in the store indicating that the error page should be rendered. I could catch this exception in all the slices and then dispatch this action to the ```SomeFeatureSlice```, but it's code duplication and I'm not quite sure how to address this issue another way...

Comment: Try writing it as a thunk and dispatching that, instead of writing it as a standalone function that needs to import the store.

Comment: Just as @markerikson responded, check for circular dependencies. Search inside you project to see where you import the store directly (other than in your file where the Provider is)